# Jquery AJAX post to PHP not work

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

This is jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Main').change(function () {
        var Sel = $(this).val();
        console.log(Sel);
        $(".Subselect").hide();
        $(".lastSel").hide();
        $("#" + Sel).show();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "test.php",
            data: "id=" + Sel + "&part_id="+$(this).attr('name'), //part_id = region
            success: function(data) {
                $(".region").html(html);
            }
           });
    });
    $('.Subselect').change(function () {
        var subSel = $(this).val();
        console.log(subSel);
        $(".lastSel").hide();
        $("#" + subSel).show();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "test.php",
            data: "id=" + subSel + "&part_id="+$(this).attr('name'), //part_id = city
            success: function(data) {
                $(".city").html(html);
            }
           });
    })
});
```

This is mysql table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `s_countries` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `code` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id_name` (`name`),
  KEY `id_code` (`code`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `s_regions` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `countryid` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id_countryid` (`countryid`),
  KEY `id_name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `s_cities` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `countryid` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `regionid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id_name` (`name`),
  KEY `id_regionid` (`regionid`),
  KEY `id_countryid` (`countryid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

This is mailtest.php (i tried many options, but cat do it work) here is example in (html + Jquery http://jsfiddle.net/Nazaret2005/bPUbb/

```
<?
require "include/db.php";
dbconn(true);
loggedinorreturn(true);


echo "<form method=\"POST\">";
$cat = "<select id='Main' name='country'>";
$cat .= "<option value='0'>Выбрать</option>";
$results = do_mysql_query("SELECT id, code, name FROM s_countries") or sqlerr(__FILE__, __LINE__); 
while($c = mysqli_fetch_array($results)){
$cat .= "<option value='".$c['id']."'>".$c['name']."</option>";
}
$cat .= "</select>";
echo $cat;
echo "<select name='region' class='Subselect'>";
echo "<option value='0'>-Выбрать-</option>";
echo "</select>";
?>
```

and this is test.php

```
<?
require_once("include/db.php");
dbconn(true);

if(isset($_POST['id'])){
$id=(int)$_POST['id'];
$res = do_mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM s_regions WHERE countryid = '".$id."'") or sqlerr(__FILE__, __LINE__); 
if(mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0){
while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
echo "<option value='".$r['id']."'>".$r['name']."</option>";
}
} }

?>
```

I wanna do this work with database like in html example http://jsfiddle.net/Nazaret2005/bPUbb/ , countries, regions and cities.
But i can't do it work....

If it's ease for some one. please help to do it work. thanks

Comment: what u get error ? or u got an error in colsole ?

Comment: did you check browser's console for the ajax request...?

Comment: @Sudhir yes i check, ajax reques needed work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is i found two mistake..

1. change ajax type to "`GET`" coz u sending data in url
2. change in test.php `$_GET['id']` insted of `$_POST`

made changes abouve and lets see what happen..

OR try this .. IF u want to send data using `POST`

if you want to send data using post then

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Main').change(function () {
        var Sel = $(this).val();
        console.log(Sel);
        $(".Subselect").hide();
        $(".lastSel").hide();
        $("#" + Sel).show();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "test.php",
            data: {id: Sel ,part_id: $(this).attr('name'), //part_id = region
            success: function(data) {
                $(".region").html(data);
            }
           });
    });
    $('.Subselect').change(function () {
        var subSel = $(this).val();
        console.log(subSel);
        $(".lastSel").hide();
        $("#" + subSel).show();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "test.php",
            data: {id:subSel ,part_id :$(this).attr('name'), //part_id = city
            success: function(data) {
                $(".city").html(data);
            }
           });
    })
});
```

and in ur PHP file keep it same

Comment: Work (its show me results) but why it work with get and don't work with post ? thanks (but its not critical)

Answer (score 0):

change the `$(".city").html(html); to`$(".city").html(data);. your  mention as a `function(data)` so call as html(data) ok.

Comment: add class='city' on your form input tag for cities. there yor mentioned class='Subselect'  change that.

Comment: i change and nothing happend :(

Comment: alert the data in the place of $(".city").html(data); write alert(data); and let me know what is the out put

Answer (score 0):

Make sure about

```
data: "id=" + Sel + "&part_id="+$(this).attr('name'),
```

Sel variable and $(this).attr('name') have value and you are getting that value.